# Why does the length of the wire matter to the value of the pull up resistors?

Tags: digital-logic, impedance, transmission-line, pullup

In this [DHT-11 datasheet](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/DHT11-Temperature-Sensor.pdf) the following sentence was mentioned (on page 4)

> A typical application circuit recommended cable length shorter than 20 meters with a 5.1K pull-up resistor when greater than 20 meters when the pull-up resistor to reduce the actual situation.

The sentence is not so obvious, and I don't understand it very well but what I get is that the length of the wire matters in choosing the value of the pull-up resistors.

Now:

**Why** does the value of the pull-up resistors depend on the length of the wire (I can guess that it has to do with the transmission line parasitic inductance and capacitance but I wasn't sure that it's a big deal on 20 meters or so).

**Is** my guess correct?

**What** are the reasons to need a pullup resistor on logic gates if it will draw very little current anyway and is there anything else other than that was mentioned?

**How** can I get this values of the resistors, does it have a formula of some kind?

Comment: The same sentence in [another translation](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf) reads "When the connecting cable is shorter than 20 metres, a 5K pull-up resistor is recommended; when the connecting cable is longer than 20 metres, choose a appropriate pull-up resistor as needed."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, a cable has parallel conductors with isolation in between, and that is a capacitor.

For example CAT5 cable has about 52 pF of capacitance per meter, and the longer the wire is, the more there is capacitance between a data and ground wires, and it takes longer for the capacitance to charge and discharge, given a certain current that is used to drive the wire.

As the DHT11 sensor use open drain communication, it means that it can only pull the wire down to ground actively, or let it float, as it cannot push the wire high. Therefore, the resistor is the only device that can bring the bus voltage high, by charging the wire capacitances.

So with longer cable, there is more capacitance, and to charge it within a certain time that is required to meet the high and low timing of the communication protocol, the resistance value must be low enough to charge the capacitance fast enough.

The formula is the same than for any RC system that charges exponentially. You have the time it needs to rise from certain logic low voltage to certain logic high voltage, the capacitance, and resistance.

But as the DHT11 datasheet does not give any real voltage or current specifications for it's data IO pin, there are no values to calculate anything. A real datasheet would give these values, so that minimum resistance value can be calculated from the maximum current the IO pin is able to sink, and then the maximum resistance value is determined by the capacitance of the bus, so that the signal rise time specification for the protocol is met.

Answer (score 1):

@JustMe has already pointed out the effect of capacitance between conductors.

You might react (no pun intended) to that by deciding to use extremely low capacitance wiring. Run your ground and signal wires a few centimetres apart, and you've dropped the capacitance drastically. Separate them by a few meters, and it's drastically lower still. At least in theory, you can choose a distance, and from it compute how far you need to separate your conductors to keep capacitance below whatever limit you choose.

But, no matter how low you keep the capacitance, the wire still has inductance. So a given length of wire acts like an inductor in series with a perfect conductor. Just like capacitance between the signal and ground, the inductance of the wires acts as a low pass filter, increasing the rise time you get from a given "strength" of driver.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this pull up resistor is explained in the next paragraph of the datasheet:

> single bus usually requires an external approximately 5.1kΩ pull up resistor, so that when the bus is idle, the state is high.

Serial communication must always keep a high state when idle.

In their explanation, we are lost in translation.
I think the meaning is this:
Add a 5.1K resistor when the line is longer than 20m.

The resistor can be between 4.7 and 10K, in reality. Not precisely 5.1K.

[Another conversation about this sensor - external link -](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=165562.0)